# Python 2.7.11 write output to a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I am trying to figure out how to write the results to a text file. Here is my code:

```
from os import getenv
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(getenv("APPDATA") + "\..\Local\...sanitized")
conn3 = sqlite3.connect(getenv("APPDATA") + "\..\Local\...sanitized")
conn1 = sqlite3.connect(getenv("APPDATA") + "\..\Local\...sanitized")
cursor3 = conn3.cursor()
cursor1 = conn1.cursor()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT ...sanitized')
for result in cursor.fetchall():
    ...sanitized
    if password:
        print "Site: " + result[0]
        print 'Username: ' + result[1]
        print 'Password: ' + password
        print '---------------------------------------------'
cursor3.execute("...sanitized") 
print("fetchall:")
result = cursor3.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)

cursor1.execute("...sanitized") 
print("fetchall:")
result = cursor1.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)
```

---

I have tried f = open('output.txt') at the beginning of the code and placed

```
f.write(r) # and I tried 
f.write(result) # after defining it near bottom as these are my variables 
f.close()# :(
```

The traceback says it was expecting a string?

Can someone help explain what should go into the print(here) ? I am trying to grasp the concepts but don't quite get it yet

Thanks

Comment: If you are using Unix, just pipe the output to a file: `python myscript.py > output.txt`

Comment: I am using windows for this :( Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: So is your code successfully printing the strings to the screen in your loop, and it's just not writing to the file? Also, could you paste the exact string error message you are getting?

Comment: Related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Answer (score 8):

First, you want to make sure you open the file for writing:

```
f=open("output.txt","w")
```

Then you could use:

```
for r in result:
    print >> f, r
```

At the end of your script, make sure you use:

```
f.close()
```

Alternatively, you may need to cast your `r` to a string `print >> f, str(r)`

Comment: Hi I have done this and I get error from this : print "Site: " + result[0]

Comment: Use `print "Site: " + str(result[0])`

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you need to specify that you want to write to the file, by using the argument `'w'`.

It is best practice to use `with` when opening your file. It will notably ensure your file is closed properly, even if there's an exception.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for r in result:
        f.write(str(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `result` is a list, whereas `write` expects a string. So instead of `f.write(result)` you could try either `f.write(str(result))` or, to get an output exactly as in your script:

```
for r in result:
    f.write(r)
```

---

Alternatively, you could import and then override the `print` function from Python 3, so that everything you `print` is automatically written to the file:

```
from __future__ import print_function

_print = print # reference to original print function
outfile = open("output.txt", "w") # file to write output to, mode is 'w' for writing
def print(*args, **kwargs):
    """new print function always writing to file"""
    _print(*args, file=outfile, **kwargs)

print("foo")
print("bar", end=" ")
print("blub")

outfile.close()
```

Or similarly, overwriting `sys.stdout`, and then just use `print` normally:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("output.txt", "w")
```

Comment: f.write(str(result)) worked, but why? Is it because converting to str?

Comment: @SafetyNetter Yep, that's exactly the reason. `write` expects a string, so you have to convert whatever you pass into it to string first. It will not do that conversion for you.